# Extract lines after a pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I have 50 files in a folder and all have a common pattern "^^". I want to print everything after "^^" and append the filename and print out all the extracted lines to one output file. While my code works fine with a single file it doesn't work on all the files.

```
awk '/\^^/{getline; getline; print FILENAME; print}' *.txt > output
```

Example

1.txt

```
     ghghh hghg 
       ghfg hghg hjg
            jhhkjh 
    kjhkjh kjh

^^ 
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

2.txt

```
hghjhg hgj 
 jhgj

            jhgjh kjgh

        jhg

^^ 
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Desired output.txt

```
1.txt
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
2.txt
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

My actual output

```
1.txt
ghghh hghg
1.txt
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Comment: Do you want to "print everything after `^^`"?  Or just the single line after `^^`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the line after `^^`, try:

```
$ awk 'f{print FILENAME ORS $0; f=0} /\^\^/{f=1}' *.txt
1.txt
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
2.txt
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

How it works:

- `f{print FILENAME ORS $0; f=0}`

  If variable `f` is true (nonzero), print the filename, the output record separator, and the current line.  Then set `f` back to zero.
- `/\^\^/{f=1}`

  If the current line contains `^^`, set `f` to one.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME; f=0} f; $1=="^^"{f=1}' *.txt
1.txt
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
2.txt
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Answer (score 0):

I like a more "bash(ish)" approach.

```sh
grep -Hn '^^' *.txt |
cut -d: -f1,2 --output-delimiter=' ' |
while read f n; do echo $f; tail $f -n+$((n+1)); done
```

- `grep -Hn` will tell the line number of your pattern.
- With `cut` we get only the needed fields, as we need.
- In a loop we `read` the two informations into variables, to use they freely as we need.
- The `tail` can read not only the last `N` lines, but also all lines from `+N` if you use the plus signal.
- We can do arithmetic operation inside `$((...))` to jump the pattern line.

And it solves your issue. And it can print all lines after the pattern, not only the next one.

Answer (score 0):

use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} FNR==1,/\^\^/{next}1' *.txt
```

**Where:**

- print FILENAME when FNR == 1
- `FNR==1,/\^\^/{next}`: all lines between FNR==1 and the first line matching `^^` will be skipped
- `1` at the end to print the rest of lines after the matched `^^` line

Answer (score 0):

let your files' name are 1 to 50 with txt type

```
for f in {1..50}.txt
{
  sed -nE "/^\^\^\s*$/{N;s/.+\n(.+)/$f\n\1/p}" $f>$f.result.txt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following outputs only if we have a file that matches our pattern:

```
awk 'FNR==1 { f=0 }; f; /\^\^/ { f=1; print FILENAME }' *.txt > output
```

1. Reset flag `f` on every new file.
2. Print if `f` is set.
3. Set `f` and `print FILENAME` if we match our pattern.

This one prints out the `FILENAME` regardless of matching pattern:

```
awk 'FNR==1 { f=0; print FILENAME }; f; /\^\^/ { f=1 }' *.txt > output
```

We can adjust the pattern matching in step 3 in accord with whatever is required... exact matching for instance can be done with `$0=="^^"`.

Answer (score 0):

Stealing from some answers and comments to your previous question on this topic, you can also use `grep -A` and format the output with sed.

```
$ grep -A100 '^^' *.txt | sed '/\^^/d;/--/d;s/-/\n/'
1.txt
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
2.txt
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Assuming 100 lines is sufficient, and that you don't have hyphens of your own.

If you only need one line, use `-A1`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -s '1,/^^^/{/^^^/F;d}' file1 file2 file3 ... >fileOut
```